# Linux terminal, how to pass to an argument to another argument C executable

Tags: c, bash, terminal, arguments

I wrote two little programs in C, `crypt` and `decrypt`.
I can call from the terminal:

```
./crypt some_argument                         it works.
```

But I want to pass to decrypt the output of `crypt`.
I already tried:

```
./decrypt $(./crypt hello)                    does not work
./crypt hello | ./decrypt                     does not work
```

Source code:
Crypt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CRYPT_KEY 5

char *crypto(char *str) {
    char *tmp_adr = str;

    while (*str != 0) {
        *str += CRYPT_KEY;
        str++;
    }
    return tmp_adr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Crypted message: %s\n", crypto(argv[1]));
}
```

Decypt is the same, but with a minus here:

```
*str -= CRYPT_KEY;
```

Someone know how to do that?

Comment: What is `some_argument`? A text string? How do you call `./decrypt`? Does `crypt` output binary data?

Comment: Post output of your crypt program. Does you decrypt program read data to decrypt from argument or stdin?

Comment: One possible issue is, crypt's output is NOT just encrypted string, instead there is extra text, "Crypted message:" , can the decrypt handle it? Please remove it and take a try.

Comment: Yea, you are right @Eric thx.
Found the problem, was a stupid thing. With crypt I output an entire message "Crypted message: %s\n", so it's obvious if I give this to decrypt will not find the same thing.
The command `./decrypt $(./crypt2 culo)` works fine with the correct program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output contains spaces. You need to quote it if you want everything in `argv[1]`.

i.e. `./decrypt "$(./crypt some_argument)"`